# How can i sort my ListView data into sections

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am receiving json data from a server. Now i would like to use this data in my React Native List View. It actually works great until trying to use section headers correctly. I get data like this:

```
var data = [
  {name: Categorie1, value: Blabla1 },
  {name: Categorie2, value: BlaBla2}, 
  {name: Categorie1, value: BlaBla3}
];
```

Now how can i tell my list view to display Categorie1 as one section and Categorie2 as a second section. Kind of sorting the List in to sections... Right now it is displayed in my app like this:

```
Header -> Categorie1
Body   -> Blabla
Header -> Categorie2
Body   -> BlaBla2
Header -> Categorie1
Body   -> BlaBla3
```

And i want it like this:

```
Header -> Categorie1
Body   -> Blabla
Body   -> BlaBla3
Header -> Categorie2
Body   -> BlaBla2
```

Comment: I think you should check this post out. It explains in great detail about how to render sections properly in ListView. http://moduscreate.com/react-native-listview-with-section-headers/